# Algebraic Equation Vexation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I was asked to help my sister with a bit of precalculus homework and completely drew a blank upon encountering this problem.

I believe it was asking to "balance the equation, and set the answer to zero."

This IS the equation

(x+1)^-1=(x^-1)+1

The answers were given.
I BELIEVE they were 4 and 1.3333 (though I'm not 100% certain on that.)

I'm interested in the journey however, not the destination.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

So we want to solve

$$\frac{1}{x + 1} = \frac{1}{x} + 1$$

Multiplying throughout by $x(x+1) = x^2 + x$,

$$x = (x + 1) + x^2 + x$$

$$x = x^2 + 2x + 1$$
$$x^2 + x + 1 = 0$$

Unfortunately, this equation does not have any real solutions for $x$. This is because

$$\begin{align}x^2 + x + 1 &= \left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2  + 1 - \frac{1}{4}\\
&=\left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}\\
&\ge \frac{3}{4} > 0\end{align}$$

for all real values of $x$. That is to say, the $x^2 + x + 1$ is always greater than $0$. You can consult the [Wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2F%28x%20%2B%201%29%20%3D%201%20%2F%20x%20%2B%201) directly to verify that no real solutions exist.

Comment: I truly appreciate the help!